# Swift struct item value not changing with function

Tags: swift, function, struct

I have the code below but even when the function `newMethod(newName: String)` is added to the class, the value of `username` isn't changing for the variable `user`. The Profile structure is defined in a different class. What am I doing wrong? Note: I'm using the LBTAComponents pod.

```
import LBTAComponents

class ProfileDatasource: Datasource {
    let placeholderIV: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        return imageView
    }()

    var user = Profile(username: String(), school: "fat", rating: 48, friends: 73, posts: 98, docs: 3, bioText: "Hi I'm a sophomore from Cyprus Bay and can help with most fields relating to high school math.", profileImage: UIImageView(), bgImage: UIImageView())

    func newThing(newName: String) {
        let newName = "Hi"
        print(newName)
        ProfileDatasource().user.username = newName
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your `newName` local variable is hiding your `newName` parameter.

Comment: Unrelated but replace `String()` with `""`.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
ProfileDatasource().user.username = newName
```

creates a new var mainly by this `ProfileDatasource()` , you need

```
self.user.username = newName
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't seem to work either :( thanks though

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you're trying to mutate the `username` property, you're

1. Creating an entirely new `ProfileDatasource` object
2. Getting the `user` property from the new `ProfileDatasource`
3. Setting the `username` on that to `newName`

After that, your new `ProfileDatasource` is deallocated and nothing ever really changes. If you want to mutate the `user` property, you can just omit the new object creation, like this:

```
user.username = newName
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't seem to work either :( thanks though

Comment: This is definitely at least part of the solution. What are you doing, what are you expecting to happen, and what's actually happening?

Comment: @EthanWilk combine this answer with the comment I posted below your question.